# Does an nvarchar always store each character in two bytes?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I had (perhaps naively) assumed that in SQL Server, an nvarchar would store each character in two bytes. But this does not always seem to be the case. The documentation out there suggests that some characters might take more bytes. Does someone have a definitive answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

yes it does it uses 2 bytes, use datalength to get the storage size, you can't use LEN because LEN just counts the characters, see here: [The differences between LEN and DATALENGTH in SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/the-differences-between-len-and-dataleng)

```
DECLARE @n NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @n = 'A', @v='A'

SELECT  DATALENGTH(@n),DATALENGTH(@v)

---------
2 1
```

Here is what Books On Line has: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

> Character data types that are either
>   fixed-length, nchar, or
>   variable-length, nvarchar, Unicode
>   data and use the UNICODE UCS-2
>   character set.
>
> **nchar [ ( n ) ]**
>
> Fixed-length Unicode
>   character data of n characters. n must
>   be a value from 1 through 4,000. The
>   storage size is two times n bytes. The
>   ISO synonyms for nchar are national
>   char and national character.
>
> **nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]**
>
> Variable-length Unicode character
>   data. *n* can be a value from 1 through
>   4,000. max indicates that the maximum
>   storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The
>   storage size, in bytes, is two times
>   the number of characters entered + 2
>   bytes. The data entered can be 0
>   characters in length. The ISO synonyms
>   for nvarchar are national char varying
>   and national character varying.

That said unicode compression was introduced in SQL Server 2008 R2 so it might store ascii as 1 byte, you can read about unicode compression here

- [SQL Server 2008 R2 : A quick experiment in Unicode Compression](https://sqlblog.org/2009/08/11/sql-server-2008-r2-a-quick-experiment-in-unicode-compression)
- [SQL Server 2008 R2 : Digging deeper into Unicode compression](https://sqlblog.org/2009/08/23/sql-server-2008-r2-digging-deeper-into-unicode-compression)
- [More testing of Unicode Compression in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/04/more-testing-of-unicode-compression-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: Sure, but this is for a bog standard letter. In SQL Server's implementation of UCS-2, does it sometimes store it in 4 characters for the less common characters? For example, in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962(v=sql.90).aspx it says "Because UCS-2 allows for encoding of only 65,536 different code points, it does not natively handle supplementary characters, and instead treats supplementary characters as a pair of undefined Unicode surrogate characters that, when paired together, define a supplementary character."

Comment: No, I have never seen it use more than 2 characters...maybe those less common characters can't be stored..do you have an example of one...paste it in the code and see what you get back

Comment: My original confusion arose because I saw someone had blogged that they had used sp_spaceused on a table and for some reason it took up more than double the space when they were using nvarchar compared to varchar. Perhaps this could be due to more pages, or other such non-data gumf taking up the extra size?

Comment: sp_spaceused also shows free space and non clustered index space..also if the table is fragmented it will take more space

Comment: >2 byte characters can be stored (although they are held internally as UCS-2) - see the GB18030 link in my answer

Answer (score 5):

Given that there are more than 65536 characters, it should be obvious that a character cannot possibly fit in just two octets (i.e. 16 bits).

SQL Server, like most of Microsoft's products (Windows, .NET, NTFS, …) uses UTF-16 to store text, in which a character takes up either two or four octets, although as @SQLMenace points out, current versions of SQL Server use compression to reduce that.

Comment: Interesting- from other things I've seen online, they mentioned that SQL Server uses UCS-2 to store text.

Comment: So are you saying that an nvarchar character could take 4 bytes?

Answer (score 4):

My understanding of this issue is that SQL server uses UCS-2 internally, but that its UCS-2 implementation has been hacked to support [a subset of characters of up to 4 bytes in the GB18030 character set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180991.aspx), which are stored as UCS-2 but are transparently converted by the database engine back to multibyte characters when queried.

Surrogate/supplementary characters aren't fully supported - the implementation of a number of SQL server string functions doesn't support surrogate pairs, as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180942.aspx).