# What size to use when moving from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ascii, varchar, nvarchar

I have a column in a table that is `VARCHAR(64)`, I started seeing some strange characters which are obviously not storing correctly, for example:

**QuÃ©bec**

I think I should change the column type to `NVARCHAR(128)` - but would like to get that validated by the Database community. From what I understand `VARCHAR` stores half the size as `NVARCHAR`, so I would need to double the `VARCHAR(64)` to `NVARCHAR(128)` - is that right? I think this question is basically: is Unicode twice as much space as ASCII?

Comment: It's a number of characters in the parens. So what fit `varchar(64)` - would fit `nvarchar(64)` as well

Comment: Ah good to know. Do you think moving to NVARCHAR will solve the problem with the "Quabec" issue above?

Comment: it should, if you send the proper data from the client. I mean - if it's not broken originally and is a valid unicode string

Comment: use nvarchar,nchar when you need to store Unicode character else use var-char,char.so currently your data-type is correct.

Answer (score 4):

`NVARCHAR(64)` holds 64 unicode characters, which takes up 128 bytes (but you don't need to know or care about that).

You specify size in characters, not bytes.

Comment: "which takes up 128 bytes" --- uhm, why? Does it count 3 or 4 bytes character as more than 1 character?

Comment: @zerkms yes, I believe it does. See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713608/does-an-nvarchar-always-store-each-character-in-two-bytes

Comment: I don't see anything there that states that 4 bytes unicode character will be treated as 2 characters

Comment: See the [Technical Introduction](http://www.unicode.org/standard/principles.html) to Unicode. Books Online says "SQL Server supports the Unicode Standard, Version 3.2."

Comment: Hmm. I was reading too fast, perhaps. But see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962.aspx) - "Both SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 can store surrogate pairs, even though UCS-2 is not aware of surrogates. SQL Server treats the surrogate pairs as two undefined Unicode characters rather than as a single character".

Comment: Unicode contains characters from U+000000 to U+10FFFF. An NCHAR or NVARCHAR will hold a single Unicode character in the range of U+000000 to U+00FFFF. A single Unicode character above U+00FFFF will be stored as two characters: a high surrogate and a low surrogate. As a result, if you only know that you want to store X Unicode characters, you cannot know how many NCHAR or NVARCHAR to allocate.